# How to handle probability notation in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm newbie for python 2.7.  I would like to create some function that knows which are variables in the given probability notation.

For example: Given a probability P(A,B,C|D,E,F) as string input.  The function should return a list of events ['A','B','C'] and a list of sample spaces ['D','E','F'].  If it is impossible to return two lists in the same time.  Returning a list of two lists would be fine.

In summary:
Input:
somefunction('P(A,B,C|D,E,F)')

Expected output: [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]

Thank you in advance

Comment: So, essentially, you need to parse an expression? And, I'm guessing, the expected output actually is `[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]`?

Comment: Opps. Yes. The expected output should be [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]

Comment: Depending on the format of your expression you may need a parser, or just a regular expression, or just several uses of [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). I suggest you try the latter.

Answer (score 0):

A simple brute-force implementation. As @fjarri pointed out if you want to do anything more complex you might need a parser (like PyParser) or at least some regular expressions.

```
def somefunction(str):
    str = str.strip()[str.index("(")+1:-1]
    left, right = str.split("|")
    return [left.split(","), right.split(",")]
```